# Push method for an array of structures

Tags: solidity

```
contract task_list {

    struct tasksStruct {
        string name;
        uint32 timestamp;
        bool is_done;
    }

    tasksStruct[] tasks;

    function add_task(string _name) public {
        tasksStruct newTask = tasksStruct(_name, now, false);
        tasks.push(newTask);
    }
    function show_opened_tasks() public view returns (uint) {
        uint count_of_opened_tasks = 0;
        for (uint i=0; i<tasks.length; i++){
            if (!tasks[i].is_done) {
                count_of_opened_tasks += 1; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

how does pushing for an array of structures work here? and why there is an error out of range of the array?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the data location for the reference types in the `add_task()` function. After fixing this, you'll be able to push to the array.

```
// added location `memory` for `name`
function add_task(string memory _name) public {
    // added location `memory` for `newTask`
    tasksStruct memory newTask = tasksStruct(_name, uint32(now), false);
    tasks.push(newTask);
}
```

Also you probably want to return the `count_of_opened_tasks` from the `show_opened_tasks()` function - otherwise you'll always get returned the default value 0.

```
function show_opened_tasks() public view returns (uint) {
    uint count_of_opened_tasks = 0;
    for (uint i=0; i<tasks.length; i++){
        if (!tasks[i].is_done) {
            count_of_opened_tasks += 1; 
        }
    }
    
    // added return
    return count_of_opened_tasks;
}
```